# Best windows forms control for a SqlProfiler UI

Tags: c#, winforms, grid

I am implementing a Windows Forms app and I want a control like what SqlProfiler has: a scrollable grid which autoscrolls as new rows are added. What's the best built-in control to use for this purpose?

Comment: AutoScroll is something you can do when you add new items, you don't need a control with that feature. Which control? It depends how much data you  have to visualize. For from small to small-medium amount of data you can even use a ListView (virtual mode, let's say no more than 10000 items). For larger datasets you'd better to use a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in `DataGridView` control and use something like:

```
yourGrid.RowsAdded += (s, a) =>
    {
        var sender = s as DataGridView;
        sender.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex =
            sender.Rows.Count - 1;
    }
```